# replacing special characters in a numpy array with blanks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, special-characters

I have a list of lists (see below) which has ? where a value is missing:

```
([[1,2,3,4],
 [5,6,7,8],
 [9,?,11,12]])
```

I want to convert this to a numpy array using np.array(test), however, the ? value is causing an issue.  What I want to do is replace the  ? with blank space '' and then convert to a numpy array so that I have the following

so that I end up with the following array:

```
([[1,2,3,4],
 [5,6,7,8],
 [9,,11,12]])
```

Comment: But is the blank space going to help make a numpy array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not have type for ?

check this

```py
a =?
print(type(a))
```

Above code will cause syntax error

It must be "?".

If this is the case then you can use

```py
list1 = ([[1,2,3,4],
          [5,6,7,8],
          [9,?,11,12]])

for i1, ele in enumerate(list1):
  for i2, x in enumerate(ele):
    if x == "?":
      list1[i1][i2] = ""
print(list1)
```

Comment: Actually, this works great with even less than the other solution

Comment: No problem - I also meant it works great, but with less code than the other solution, and also doesn't depend on whwther the data is int or not.

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension:

```
matrix = ...

new_matrix = [["" if not isinstance(x,int) else x for x in sublist] for sublist in matrix]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach using loops to find elements that can't be turned into integers and replaces them with blank spaces.

```
import numpy as np

preArray = ([[1,2,3,4],
            [5,6,7,8],
            [9,'?',11,12]])

newPreArray = []
for row in preArray:
    newRow = []

    for val in row:
        try:
            int(val)
            newRow.append(val)
        except:
            newRow.append('')

    newPreArray.append(newRow)

array = np.array(newPreArray)
```

Comment: You're welcome! I would suggest you look at the answer @frab posted too. It's essentially the same concept but its 1 line.

Answer (score 0):

For a single list you can do something like:

```
>>> myList = [4, 5, '?', 6]
>>> myNewList = [i if str(i).isdigit() else '' for i in myList]
>>> myNewList
[4,5,'',6]
```

so take that information and make it work with a list of lists.